# postfix smtpd_recipient_restrictions problem

Tags: 14.04, email, postfix

I'm trying to get my server on a.b.c.3 to accept messages and send them from a.b.c.2.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and postfix.

On the .3 server that's running a very simple installation of postfix, I'm getting this fatal error when I try to send a message.

```
 fatal: invalid "-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions" option value: missing '=' after attribute name
```

The critical part of master.cf looks like this.

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
# submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                               check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_override,
                                permit
```

What do I have wrong with my permit_mynetworks section?  There is a rbl_override file.

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently I need to uncomment the **submission** line.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot

But when I do, I get another error.
`fatal: unexpected command-line argument: submission`

Answer (score 0):

```
-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
```

avoids this error.

It's still not recognizing my networks, but that's another issue.